# AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'ids'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I got an error from this code, I am trying to change the color of the button when pressed.

The code:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<FileBrowserApp>:
    Button:
        id: 'b1'
        text: 'Select Files'
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': 0}
        size_hint: (1, 0.1)
        on_press: self.do_select
        on_press: self.background_color=[0,0,255,1]
        on_release: self.background_color=[192,192,19,1]   
''')


class FileBrowserApp(App):
    def build(self):
        try:
            if(self.out):
            self.root.remove_widget(self.out)
        except:
            pass

        self.root = FloatLayout()
        self.bn = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")

        button1 = self.ids['b1']
    
        self.bn.add_widget(button1)

        self.out = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.root.add_widget(self.out)
        self.root.add_widget(self.bn)
        
        return self.root
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "kk.py", line 120, in <module>
 app.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 800, in run
 root = self.build()
File "kk.py", line 47, in build
 button1 = self.ids['b1']
AttributeError: 'FileBrowserApp' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

is that Builder.load_string() allows more than one class to create a kv language

How to resolve this error?

Comment: your FileBrowserApp doesn't have an 'ids' attribute as you haven't defined it in the class' __init__() constructor (which you don't have); that said,  should it be self.id?

Comment: @ewong, how to connect the builder.load_string() to the constructor...

Comment: In this example, "https://stackoverflow.com/a/41967105/13447866" they did not created constructor for self.ids but this code works, could you please help me with this error, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a `Button` to the `FileBrowserApp` as you appear to attempt in your `kv`. Your construction is appropriate for adding a `Button` to a container (like a `Layout`), but an `App` is not a container. If you want to define a `Button` in your `kv` you can do it by defining a new class that extends `Button` like this:

```
class SelectFileButton(Button):
    pass
```

Then create a rule for `SelectFileButton` in the `kv`:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<SelectFileButton>:
    text: 'Select Files'
    pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': 0}
    size_hint: (1, 0.1)
    on_press: app.do_select()
    on_press: self.background_color=[0,0,255,1]
    on_release: self.background_color=[192,192,19,1]   
''')
```

This rule defines how a `SelectFileButton` should be configured, and can then be used in the `build()` method:

```
class FileBrowserApp(App):
    def build(self):
        try:
            if (self.out):
                self.root.remove_widget(self.out)
        except:
            pass

        self.root = FloatLayout()
        self.bn = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")

        # create a Button based on the kv rule
        button1 = SelectFileButton()
        self.bn.add_widget(button1)

        self.out = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.root.add_widget(self.out)
        self.root.add_widget(self.bn)

        return self.root

    def do_select(self):
        print('do select')
```

That is one way to do it, but a better approach might be to create a rule in `kv` that describes how the entire root of the `FileBrowserApp` should be built. Then the `build()` method would simply be returning that root. Or, if you put that `kv` in a file named `filebrowser.kv`, you don't even need a `build()` method. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#method-using-kv-file).