# Getting 'NoneType' when calling Camera resolution parameter

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to access Camera widget in Kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.logger import Logger
import logging
Logger.setLevel(logging.TRACE)


class MainApp(App):
    title = 'wohoo'

    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: 1280,720
        play: True
```

Full error output:

```
[TRACE  ] [Cache       ] Flushed category kv.texture from cache
[TRACE  ] [Cache       ] Flushed category kv.shader from cache
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load </home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[TRACE  ] [Image       ] '/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/glsl/default.png', populate to textures (1)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[TRACE  ] [Lang        ] Found 0 rules for <kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x7f14b22402f0>
[TRACE  ] [Lang        ] Found 1 rules for <kivy.uix.camera.Camera object at 0x7f14ab46c830>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
     resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 599, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 707, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/mark/venv/main.kv", line 4:
 ...
       2:    Camera:
       3:        id: camera
 >>    4:        resolution: 1280,720
       5:        play: True
 ...
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/mark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
     resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and using Python 3.7, Kivy version 1.11.1

(this text here is to bypass "it looks like your post is mostly code" warning,this text here is to bypass "it looks like your post is mostly code" warning,this text here is to bypass "it looks like your post is mostly code" warning)

Comment: That's indeed an interesting error, it's probably unclearly referencing something internal to Kivy. Is this the only error text? Please paste the full traceback if there's any more.

Comment: @inclement  I edited the error log again as I noticed I had one line commented out which caused other errors. I reduced error only to one now but it is the same error.

Comment: I found this topic where OP deals with the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172543/how-i-can-use-kivy-python-camera and the question has no accepted solution. 4 years ago.

Comment: The presence of an accepted solution is pretty meaningless.

Comment: @inclement  Is it possible for you to reproduce the error in virtual machine ? Given that I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, using Python 3.7.9 and latest stable release of Kivy.

Comment: I think the error indicates that you have no working camera provider. I'm afraid I'm not going to try to reproduce it. I suggest asking on the Kivy discord.

Comment: @inclement I just noticed that it worked before when it was using `camera_android.py` script. Now it's using `camera.py` script. What determines which script is ran ?